# Tail Risk Hedging for Public Pension Plan

Tags: options, fixed-income, portfolio-optimization, asset-allocation

Very simplistically, ERISA rules require corporate pension plans to use market rates to discount their liabilities.  If interest rates go up, the value of their pension liabilities goes down.  Since asset values are also marked to market using market rates, their assets have similar treatment and therefore it is self hedging (at least for the fixed income allocation.)

Public (or government) Pension Plans on the other hand do not use market interest rates to value their liabilities.  They use a target pension return, which is rarely adjusted and often do not reflect current market interest rates.  As such, the value of their liabilities remains constant (not taking into account growth due to salaries etc.)  However, their assets are marked to market in that they are carried at the current market value.  As such, this is not self hedging.

Wouldn't it make more sense for Public Pension Plans to have some type of tail risk hedge, or option like strategy, given the asymmetric impact of interest rates on their pension funded status?

Comment: I think this is more of a philosophical question than anything else. It's quite intriguing to me and something I would love to discuss, but I'm not sure it belongs on this forum.

Comment: @amdopt I was thinking of asking the question in terms of a hedge ratio of tail risk for Pension Funds but there were too many options for a tail hedge to choose from.  But this is a  key difference between these investors.  I figured I would ask the point more generally to get more participation.  I can re-ask in the context of a hedge ratio.

Comment: Yea, I get that. No need to re-ask. It just got me thinking.

Comment: @amdopt  I would be interested in hearing your thoughts.  I know you run an options portfolio and OTM options are used in many of these tail risk hedging strategies.  Should IR options be used as well for Public Plans?  How big should these hedges be, given that they are almost all underfunded?  Should non-correlated assets (like trend following) be considered a hedge (at what point is just another asset class if that is what is used as a tail hedge?)  A lot of questions on this topic that would impact quantitative finance but need to be sorted first.

Comment: Why do you write "wouldn't it make more sense"? Responsibly managed pension funds do consider this. Without liquidity risk this type of asset-liability management just means proper duration matching where the duration of the liabilities is zero (i.e. zero change if rates change). It is straightforward and also encountered in various other lines of business where liabilities or assets are not marked-to-market.

Comment: @gg  My experience with pension plans is that they generally do not follow any asset-liability matching.  They generally invest in asset classes driven by some asset allocation (usually some constrained mean variance optimization) from only the long side and then ride the performance through thick and thin (with some rebalancing).  And then face scrutiny from having large drawdowns and funding gaps.  It would seem like a tail risk hedge would put them in a better position for recovery after a drawdown.